# Can't install NetBeans, installer lock file exists

Tags: java, netbeans, locking, installation

I am trying to install NetBeans, but I get a white window "NetBeans Installer lock file exists" and it quits. I haven't had NetBeans installed on this PC before and the first time the installer started I accidentally denied admin privilege for it.

I've tried:

- to look NetBeans up in add&remove programs but it's not there.
- to search for lock file with hidden files visible.
- to find NetBeans folder ins appdata\roaming but there's none.
- try different installers

I'd really appreciate if somebody could help me with this.

Comment: why not just download the zip and unzip it?

Comment: Try it on a **virtual** or **another PC** instead, or [**see this ad-hoc list**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) from *"A Deployment Mnemonic"* and the next couple of sections. You can also try a simple **reboot** first.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, there was indeed a lock file that was created on the first "failed" run of the installer but it's not called anything netbeans, it was in C:\User\x.nbi.nbilock
found out when I was trying to run a JDK installer.